# Spring Boot - Test utility classes without Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, junit4

I have a utility package which I want to combine with a Spring boot application in the same project, instead of storing them separately.

I would like to unit test these inner utility classes which do not require the Spring context at all - I can call them from the unit test classes so starting the application is an unnecessary overhead.

- They're just classes involving some JSON parsing on files stored in the `resources` folder - in essence, they're completely independent of the Spring application (they're not services and there is no need for them to be mocked, just standard utility classes), albeit not of much use on their own.

Now, I can manually run the tests in my IDE (IntelliJ) by clicking the test icon shown, however, when I try to run them using

```
mvn test
```

I am met with:

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

Note that I can run the `junit` tests when the utility package is in a separate package (with `mvn test`) but I would like to house it under the same package as the application.

Here's my `pom.xml` if that helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>package.application.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>[3.2.2,)</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>[4.13.1,)</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        ... Other dependencies

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <start-class>package.application.Application</start-class>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

My test structure:

```
test/java
    - utility
        - category1
            - ParserTest.java
        - category2
            - SomeOtherTest.java
    - application
```

And I would like to run all the tests in the `utility` package.

Comment: Just check `mvn test -Dtest=YourclassName`, whether you are able to run or not.

Comment: @Sambit Please see the edit with my test structure, how would I specify the package?

Comment: latest spring boot uses junit5, whereas you seem to be using junit4. what's wrong with junit5? Also, you don't seem to be using standard naming for unit tests, is that on purpose? and do you have directories using standard maven naming convetion?

Comment: @eis I just used junit4 previously and felt no need to upgrade. Apologies for the crude example, my test classes are more something like `ParsingTest.java` and the maven naming convention for directories: I'd assume so given that everything runs fine when running the package separately (not combined with the spring boot application).

Comment: The standard folder for maven tests is `test`, not `tests` as shown in your tree view. Is that a typo?

Comment: @daniu Apologies, typo in the question not in my source code, I've updated the question.

Comment: Since Spring Boot 2.4.X JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) is default. I strongly recommend to change to JUnit Jupiter...Directory structure is `src/test/java` and not `src/tests/java`... please follow the conventions over configuration paradigm ... it's easier and saves a lot of time...Furthermore I strongly recommend **NOT** to use version ranges like `<version>[3.2.2,)</version>`... use fixed versions...Also take a look into [Spring Boot Release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes).

Comment: @khmarbaise I will gladly take your suggestions on board, however it's not clear to me why my unit tests are not running.

Comment: Based on the missing junit-vintage-engine to run JUnit 4 based tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided enough details for this to be reproducable, but based on information you've given, I think your junit tests are not running since the latest spring will default to junit5, not junit4, and in this case will silently ignore junit4 tests unless you've explicitly specified them to be run.

Recommended action is to upgrade to junit5.

If you want to stay on junit4, you can add this dependency so that legacy tests will be run:

```
   <!--JUnit Jupiter Engine to depend on the JUnit4 engine and JUnit 4 API  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity on my end, I had no idea junit5 was a thing haha. Thanks for the help!